# Prevent jquery draggable from getting -1 px when snap is on

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I'm using jQuery ui for the draggable function. I have snap on my parent object. The problem is the following: when the object snaps to the parent, it gets "top: -1px, left: -1px". 
How can I prevent this and make it snap to 0 rather than -1?

See this jfiddle + Inspector to see what I mean:

```
jsfiddle.net/Fredettiw/L0dmzstq
```

As soon as you move the rectangle, it snaps to the .page, but it gets -1px.

(Sorry i couldnt link the jsfiddle with http, because I got an Error every time I tried to save as a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only first time when the object snaps to the parent it gets "top: -1px, left: -1px". The reason is the parent border (border:1px solid black;). If you give parent border 10 px then it will get "top: -10px, left: -10px".

I have created 3 jsfiddle for you. In first one I removed parent border and added background property for parent (background: lightgray;) to test whether the parent border is causing issue which indeed is the root cause of the issue.

```
Please have a look at first jsfiddle:

     http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/cfcvyng3/
```

In second jsfiddle I have not removed border from parent but added top and left margin to draggable object.(ex. if parent border is 10px then give top and left margin 10 px to draggable object). It is working fine.

```
Second jsfiddle  URL:

     http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/7k8h131e/
```

In third jsfiddle I have not changed your CSS but jQuery code. Though this fiddle also serves the purpose but in this code draggable object can be dragged within the parent object not outside of it.

```
Third jsfiddle URL:

     http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/fr4bcpu5/
```

Second jsfiddle is working fine and fixes your issue.

Comment: Hey man, the last one is perfect!! It's exactly what I needed. First problem was the -1px and the next problem was how the hell do I keep it inside of this. Is this the containment property?

Comment: I have to wait 1 hour for bounty, but you will get it :)

Comment: Yes, containment property set the constraint to keep it inside of parent.